# Overlaying a green screen intro over video using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

Can someone please help me with a program that overlays a green screen intro in the start of the video.
Basically I need help with a FFMPEG program that overlays a green screen video which is the intro of the video, so the first few seconds are with the green screen overlay and then the normal video continues.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [chromakey](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#chromakey) and [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filters.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i green.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]chromakey=color=0x61e577:similarity=0.01[gs];[0:v][gs]overlay=eof_action=pass" output.mp4
```